# Best way to write an or is equal statement

Tags: php, comparison, equals, equality

Hello $mostamazingforumforfastanswersever.

I have a quick silly question; what is the best way to write this :

```
if ($curpageurl == "www.mysite.com/this" || "www.mysite.com/this/")

{
echo 'this is the this page'; 
}
```

and if it isn't, then I need to call

```
while (isset($somevariable)
{
echo '$somevariable';
}
```

and if that variable isn't set and we are not on this page, then

```
else 
{
echo 'we are not on this page and the variable isn't set';
}
```

I know I'm not far from the right answer, and this actually works as is but only if I remove the || this/ portion of my first if statement. Is there a better way to write the or is equal to portion? || == for example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($curpageurl == "www.mysite.com/this" || $curpageurl == "www.mysite.com/this/")
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I wasn't far hehe :p

Answer (score 0):

If you are only doing this because of the /, maybe the simplest way would be just use substr or something like this to just get the part you want.

So check if the last char is /, if so get the $curpageurl to the last char -1

I am only suggesting this in case you have more possible values for $curpageurl

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that! But there is only 2 possible values of interest, which is with and without the /. Anything else will yield the "else" statements.